# Laravel validation only allow certain characters

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I am doing some form validation at the moment, and I need to only allow certain characters to be submitted, `qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
1234567890
!@£$%^&*()’~*-_+` alpha, alpha_num & alpha_dash don't cover all the characters, I know I can create a custom validation rule, of which I have done for another validation case, but I assume I would need regex to check the submitted string, and I have no idea where to start with regex.

Comment: Read about character class. [`character class`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 1):

A regex rule would work for this. Here's a sample rule:

```php
'some_field' => 'required|regex:/^[A-z0-9!@£$%^&*()\'~*_+\-]+$/',
```

In the above regex, I replaced your smart quote `’` with a single quote `'`. If this is incorrect let me know and I can update the regex.

For an explanation of the regular expression, check out regex101.com.

Note in the regex the single quote has also been escaped with a leading backslash to get PHP to interpret the quote as part of the string and not the end of the string.

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/u1h) to shorten it

Comment: While this answer works in regex101, I get the following error in Laravel, `Unknown modifier '&amp;'`

Comment: @Udders can you paste your full rule here? I haven't been able to reproduce that error.